# How do i store a whole void method in array variable

Tags: java, arrays

```
public void body()
    String name = "", address = "",checkin = "", checkout = "";

    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
    for(k =1;;k++)
        {

        }
```

I need to store whole method in a array variable at once.
well actually for every loop i want to create a element in array.

Comment: I think maybe you want a `class Reservation` with fields for those variables.

Comment: what exactly do you want to store in your array ?

Comment: I want to store the statements that i pass thorough for loop every time as a single element in array

Answer (score 1):

Like chrylis said in his comment you could create a class Reservation with the fields you want to store.

```
 public class Reservation {

     private String name; 
     private String address;
     private String checkin;
     private String checkout;

     public Reservation(String name, String address, String checkin, String checkout) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.checkin = checkin;
      this.checkout = checkout;
     }

     //getters and setters ...

    }
```

Then you can create a new Object of it in your method and add it to your array

```
ArrayList<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();
 for(k =1;;k++) {
  reservations.add(new Reservation(...));
 }
```

I used an `ArrayList` instead of an `Array` because you can add as many elements as you want to an `ArrayList`